# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Replacements can not be multi

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, spring-data-mongodb, mongodb-java

I am using the following software and their versions:

- mongodb: 3.4.10
- spring-data-mongodb:  2.10.1.RELEASE
- mongodb java driver: 3.4.3
- spring boot: 1.5.10.RELEASE

MongoDB schema:

```
   {
        "_id" : ObjectId("some id"),
        "a":{/* Complex Structure */},
        "b": [/* Array of transaction records */], 
        "c": {/* Some additional 50 fields with mixture of various data types  */ }
   }
```

Java code: TransactionMap class is a java.util.HashMap

```
mongoTemplate.updateFirst(query, update, TransactionMap.class);
```

Exception traced:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Replacements can not be multi
```

When will the above exception be thrown?

Comment: The house style here is not to sign posts, and when editors find a signed post, we tend to remove it. The profile card is regarded as sufficient sign of authorship here.